# How do I graph a-b=0?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Lets say a=x+y and b=2x-y and I want to plot a-b=0. I can manually rewrite this from (x+y)-(2x-y)=0 to y=.5x which makes it trivial to graph, but how do I rewrite it in code? Given x how do I calculate y if all I have is (x+y)-(2x-y)=0?

To be more specific, I am trying to graph the decision boundary of a neural network. I want to be able to change the layers and outputs at will, essentially changing the function I get as an output.

[This is an example of an output I could get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uy7ip.gif):

```
(x_1 w_2 + x_2 w_2 + b_1) w_7
+ (x_1 w_3 + x_2 w_4 + b_2) w_8
+ (x_1 w_5 + x_2 w_6 + b_3) w_9
+ b_4 (x_1 w_1 + x_2 w_2 + b_1) w_10
+ (x_1 w_3 + x_2 w_4 + b_2) w_11
+ (x_1 w_5 + x_2 w_6 + b_3) w_12
+ b_5
```

It's a 1 by 2 matrix and I know all values except x2 which is the y-axis. In order to draw the decision boundary I have to calculate a-b=0 where a and b both contain x and y. I can manually separate y to get y=... ,but that's not an option if the results in the output matrix change. How do I seperate/calculate the y?

I am using c# in Unity and passing the points on the graph into the LineRenderer.

Comment: @TomTales: can you provide a concrete example (with numbers or formulae)? Right now it is hard to understand how you would come rfom `a=x+y` and `b=2x-y` to a formula that spans tens of terms

Comment: @TomTales: I copied your image to the question, I hope I got it right

Comment: Is sampling of the two functions an option? E.g. if you have `f(x)=-x` and `g(x)=2x` you could compose both to `h(x) = f(x) - g(x)` and then compute `h(0.1)`, `h(0.2)`, etc.

Comment: @knittl Yeah I was trying to simplify it for myself. Here's a concrete example: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/crmeebqnfb
And thanks for adding the image

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I found the solution the same day of posting the question but had already been messing about for days. It turned out to be a math question after all.
Here's a link to the specific setup for the neural network using a linear activation: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/crmeebqnfb

I manually rewrote the matrix multiplication for this specific setup into a function and was looking for a way to do that for any size and number of invisible layers.
The solution I found is to separate the input matrix into x1 and x2 and separately do the matrix multiplication for them. The x1 value gets the biases added but the x2 doesn't and the first weight matrix has to be split in 2 so x1 can get multiplied with the first row and x2 with the second row.
If you then do the matrix multiplication from there you'll get two 2 matrices like this:
[firstx1answer secondx1answer] [firstx2answer secondx2answer]
And then you can put them into this function:

[image]

Edit for better clarification: [image]

Maybe a bit confusing but here's my code. CreateDecisionBoundaryPoints is where this is implemented:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using System.IO;
using System;

[ExecuteAlways]
public class Controller : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform LineRenderer;
    public GameObject textPrefab;
    public GameObject pointPrefab;
    public Transform weightsUI;
    public Transform biasesUI;

    [Range(.001f, .1f)] public float delta;
    public int numberOfHiddenLayers;

    public bool debugWeightMatrices;
    public bool debugBiasMatrices;

    [HideInInspector] public string[] dataValues;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (Application.isPlaying)
        {
            //read file
            int numberOfLines;
            dataValues = ReadData("D:\\Documents\\Unity Projects\\Learning Machine Learning\\Assets\\Data.csv", out numberOfLines);
            int numOfOutputNeurons = CreatePointsUI(numberOfLines, dataValues);

            //create layerSizes for example [2,3,2]
            int[] layerSizes = new int[numberOfHiddenLayers + 2];
            layerSizes[0] = (dataValues.Length / numberOfLines) - 1;
            layerSizes[numberOfHiddenLayers + 1] = numOfOutputNeurons;
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfHiddenLayers; i++)
            {
                layerSizes[i+1] = Mathf.Max((dataValues.Length / numberOfLines) - 1, numOfOutputNeurons) + 1;
            }

            //create the actual matrices
            List<float[,]> weights = new List<float[,]>();
            List<float[]> biases = new List<float[]>();
            MakeTheMatrices(layerSizes, out weights, out biases);
            //fill weights with random values
            RandomlyFillMatrices(weights);
            //print matrices to make sure they're the right size and filled randomly
            if (debugWeightMatrices)
                Debug.Log(PrintMatrices(weights, "Weight Matrices"));
            if (debugBiasMatrices)
                Debug.Log(PrintMatrices(biases, "Bias Matrices"));

            LineRenderer.GetComponent<DrawDecisionBoundary>().DrawLine(CreateDecisionBoundaryPoints(weights, biases, delta));
        }
    }

    public struct OutputNeuronsAndColours
    {
        public string value;
        public Color color;

        public OutputNeuronsAndColours(string value, Color color)
        {
            this.value = value;
            this.color = color;
        }
    }

    public void DoTheWeightsStufUI(int weights)
    {
        int cwn = 0;
        List<Transform> ws = new List<Transform>();
        foreach (Transform child in weightsUI)
        {
            cwn++;
            ws.Add(child);
        }
        int wta = weights - cwn;
        for (int i = wta; i < 0; i++)
        {
            cwn--;
            DestroyImmediate(ws[cwn].gameObject);
            ws.RemoveAt(cwn);
        }
        for (int i = wta; i > 0; i--)
        {
            cwn++;
            GameObject weight = Instantiate(textPrefab, weightsUI);
            weight.GetComponentInChildren<TMP_Text>().SetText("W" + cwn.ToString());
        }
    }
    public void DoTheBiasesStufUI(int biases)
    {
        int cbn = 0;
        List<Transform> bs = new List<Transform>();
        foreach (Transform child in biasesUI)
        {
            cbn++;
            bs.Add(child);
        }
        int bta = biases - cbn;
        for (int i = bta; i < 0; i++)
        {
            cbn--;
            DestroyImmediate(bs[cbn].gameObject);
            bs.RemoveAt(cbn);
        }
        for (int i = bta; i > 0; i--)
        {
            cbn++;
            GameObject bias = Instantiate(textPrefab, biasesUI);
            bias.GetComponentInChildren<TMP_Text>().SetText("B" + cbn.ToString());
        }
    }

    string[] ReadData(string path, out int numberOfLines)
    {
        List<string> data_values = new List<string>();

        StreamReader strReader = new StreamReader(path);
        bool endOfFile = false;
        int numOfLines = 0;
        while (!endOfFile)
        {
            string data_string = strReader.ReadLine();
            if (data_string == null)
            {
                endOfFile = true;
                break;
            }
            else
                numOfLines += 1;

            data_values.AddRange(data_string.Split(','));
        }

        numberOfLines = numOfLines;
        return data_values.ToArray();
    }
    int CreatePointsUI(int numberOfLines, string[] dataValues)
    {
        string[] possibleOutputs = new string[numberOfLines];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++)
        {
            possibleOutputs[i] = dataValues[(i * (dataValues.Length / numberOfLines)) + ((dataValues.Length / numberOfLines) - 1)];
        }

        List<OutputNeuronsAndColours> outputNeurons = new List<OutputNeuronsAndColours>(possibleOutputs.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < possibleOutputs.Length; i++)
        {
            bool contains = false;
            for (int x = 0; x < outputNeurons.Count; x++)
            {
                if (possibleOutputs[i] == outputNeurons[x].value)
                    contains = true;
            }
            if (!contains)
                outputNeurons.Add(new OutputNeuronsAndColours(possibleOutputs[i], new Color(UnityEngine.Random.Range(0f, 1f), UnityEngine.Random.Range(0f, 1f), UnityEngine.Random.Range(0f, 1f))));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++)
        {
            GameObject point = Instantiate(pointPrefab);
            point.transform.position = new Vector2(float.Parse(dataValues[i * (dataValues.Length / numberOfLines)]), float.Parse(dataValues[(i * (dataValues.Length / numberOfLines)) + 1]));

            foreach (OutputNeuronsAndColours value in outputNeurons)
            {
                if (value.value == dataValues[(i * (dataValues.Length / numberOfLines)) + ((dataValues.Length / numberOfLines) - 1)])
                    point.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = value.color;
            }
        }

        return outputNeurons.Count;
    }

    public static void MakeTheMatrices(int[] layerSizes, out List<float[,]> weights, out List<float[]> biases)
    {
        List<float[,]> tempWeights = new List<float[,]>();
        List<float[]> tempBiases = new List<float[]>();

        for (int i = 0; i < layerSizes.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            tempWeights.Add(new float[layerSizes[i], layerSizes[i + 1]]);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < layerSizes.Length; i++)
        {
            List<float> temp = new List<float>();
            for (int x = 0; x < layerSizes[i]; x++)
                temp.Add(0);
            tempBiases.Add(temp.ToArray());
        }

        weights = tempWeights;
        biases = tempBiases;
    }
    public static void RandomlyFillMatrices(List<float[,]> matrices)
    {
        foreach (float[,] matrix in matrices)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < matrix.GetLength(1); x++)
                {
                    matrix[i, x] = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-3f, 3f);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static string PrintMatrices(List<float[,]> matrices, string name = "Count")
    {
        string returnString = matrices.Count + " " + name;
        foreach (float[,] matrix in matrices)
        {
            returnString += " (" + matrix.GetLength(0) + ", " + matrix.GetLength(1) + ")";

            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                string log = "";
                if (i == 0)
                    log += "[";
                else
                    log += " ";

                for (int x = 0; x < matrix.GetLength(1); x++)
                {
                    log += matrix[i, x];
                    if(x != matrix.GetLength(1) - 1)
                        log += " ";
                }

                if (i == matrix.GetLength(0) - 1)
                    log += "]";

                Debug.Log(log);
            }
        }

        return returnString;
    }
    public static string PrintMatrices(List<float[]> matrices, string name = "Count")
    {
        string returnString = matrices.Count + " " + name;

        foreach (float[] matrix in matrices)
        {
            returnString += " (" + matrix.Length + ")";

            string log = "[";

            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Length; i++)
            {
                log += matrix[i];
                if (i != matrix.Length - 1)
                    log += " ";
            }

            log += "]";
            Debug.Log(log);
        }

        return returnString;
    }

    private Vector3[] CreateDecisionBoundaryPoints(List<float[,]> weights, List<float[]> biases, float delta)
    {
        //check whether there are exactly 2 input neurons
        if (weights[0].GetLength(0) != 2)
            Debug.LogError("Not exactly 2 input neurons!");

        //check whether there are exactly 2 output neurons
        if (biases[biases.Count - 1].Length != 2)
            Debug.LogError("Not exactly 2 output neurons!");

        //create the values for the first layer
        float[] weightsForFirstLayerX = new float[weights[0].GetLength(1)];
        for (int i = 0; i < weights[0].GetLength(1); i++)
        {
            weightsForFirstLayerX[i] = weights[0][0, i];
        }
        float[] denominatorValuesFirstLayer = new float[weights[0].GetLength(1)];
        for (int i = 0; i < weights[0].GetLength(1); i++)
        {
            denominatorValuesFirstLayer[i] = weights[0][1, i];
        }

        List<Vector3> pointsForGraph = new List<Vector3>();
        //Calculate the y value(s) for each x with interval delta
        for (float x = -.04f; x <= 1 + delta; x += delta) 
        {
            float[] numeratorValuesFirstLayer = new float[weightsForFirstLayerX.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < weightsForFirstLayerX.Length; i++)
                numeratorValuesFirstLayer[i] = x * weightsForFirstLayerX[i] + biases[0][i];

            //get the row matrices for the decision boundary function
            float[] numeratorResults = PassValuesThroughMatrices(numeratorValuesFirstLayer, weights, biases, true);
            float[] denominatorResults = PassValuesThroughMatrices(denominatorValuesFirstLayer, weights, biases, false);

            float y = (numeratorResults[1] - numeratorResults[0]) / (denominatorResults[0] - denominatorResults[1]);
            pointsForGraph.Add(new Vector3(x, y, -1));
        }

        return pointsForGraph.ToArray();
    }

    private float[] PassValuesThroughMatrices(float[] values, List<float[,]> weights, List<float[]> biases, bool isNumerator)
    {
        float[] previousLayer = values;
        //loop passing the previous layer values through the current layer: values = values * weights + biases
        for (int i = 1; i < weights.Count; i++)
        {
            float[] temp = new float[weights[i].GetLength(1)];
            //loop through the colums in the weight matrix
            for (int v = 0; v < weights[i].GetLength(1); v++)
            {
                float value = 0;
                //loop through the rows in the weight matrix
                for (int b = 0; b < weights[i].GetLength(0); b++)
                    value += previousLayer[b] * weights[i][b, v];
                if (isNumerator)
                    value += biases[i][v];

                temp[v] = value;
            }

            previousLayer = temp;
        }

        //return the last iteration of values
        return previousLayer;
    }
}
```